# Cant add new fragments to LinearLayout after removing other ones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a number of `LinearLayouts` which are intended to contain fragments. I am using the compatibility library fragments, manager, etc. When I am attempting to redraw the contents of the `LinearLayouts` I remove all the fragments first, then add what is needed. I don't use replace because my understanding is that it doesn't always work as expected and I need to add more than one fragment back into the layout anyway. Near as I can tell the code below should work, however when it executes, all that happens is the original fragments disappear but the new ones do not show up.

The relevant code follows:

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED called on view: " + v + " with id: " + v.getId());
        handleActionDragEntered(v, event);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

protected void handleActionDragEntered(View v, DragEvent event) {
    ArrayList<Integer> oldRow;
    switch (mState) {
    case TARGET_NOT_ENTERED:
        mState = State.TARGET_ENTERED_PARENT;
        mParentOld = mParentNew = (LinearLayout) v; //Save the parent row
        //Replace the drag view with a drop target. Need to lookup which row the parent row is.
        oldRow = mAdapter.replaceDragViewWithTarget(mDragView.getId(), 
                mRowIndices.get(mParentOld.getId()));
        redraw(mParentOld, oldRow, mAdapter.getIndiciesForRow(mRowIndices.get(mParentOld.getId())));
        break;
    case TARGET_ENTERED_PARENT:
        mState = State.TARGET_ENTERED_NEW_PARENT;
        mParentNew = (LinearLayout) v;
        oldRow = mAdapter.addDragViewToRow(mDragView, mRowIndices.get(mParentNew.getId()), getIndexInRow(event.getX(), v));
        redraw(mParentNew, oldRow, mAdapter.getIndiciesForRow(mRowIndices.get(mParentNew.getId())));
        break;
    default:
        Log.w(TAG, "Unhandled Action Drag Entered!");
    }
}

public void redraw(View v, ArrayList<Integer> oldRow, ArrayList<Integer> newRow) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    for (int oldFragment : oldRow) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Removing fragment " + oldFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(oldFragment)));
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    for (int newFragment : newRow) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Adding fragment " + newFragment + " to row: " + v.getId());
        fragmentTransaction.add(v.getId(), mAdapter.getFragmentAtIndex(newFragment), String.valueOf(newFragment));
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

There is no indication in the LogCat of any errors and all the log statements in the code report the values as expected, including callbacks from the fragments notifying that they are creating their views.

**UPDATE**

Calling `invalidate()` on the view container does not solve the problem.

**UPDATE 2**

Following the suggestion of the guest user, I tried wrapping the redraw code in a `Runnable` that is posted on the view. Currently my redraw code executes on the UI thread so I don't see this being necessary per se, but perhaps it will give some insight into what my problem may be. I have also edited the above code snippet to include Wizetux's suggestion as well as include more of the code responsible for calling the redraw function. All this is related to the drag and drop components of Android. Testing is on a Galaxy Nexus 4.1 device, however the code behavior is the same on all devices I have tried.

**UPDATE 3**

If I remove the remove transactions and execute only the add transactions, the results are as expected, so the problem seems to be related to doing the two transactions in succession. Wizetux's suggestion then makes a lot of sense to me so did I not execute it properly?

Comment: Try to call invalidate() on the LinearLayout that contains these fragments.

Comment: Tried it as suggested, no change in the results though.

Comment: Have you tried using `View.post(Runnable)` for transaction? **Edit**: Sory for not being entirely clear. I meant wrap second transaction in runnable. I had a little different but similar issue, this kind of aproach fixed it for me.

Comment: I tried this this morning to no avail. I suspect this made no difference because the code that is executing the redraw is already on the UI thread. Nevertheless, I am editing my question to show this code as well for any potential input.

Comment: @guest: when you encountered your problem were you creating transactions on a background thread or were you doing everything on the UI thread? Are you saying I should do the remove operation as I had originally and the add in its own `Runnable` from within the same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all of the (much appreciated) suggestions of those who posted, nothing seemed to solve the problem. As a result, I redesigned and rewrote the code responsible for this section of my app and the new layout design did not seem to have the problem. Specifically, not having the `LinearLayout` parents for the fragments and instead using the GridLayout directly seemed to solve the problem. I still don't see any reason why both methods can't work, but I'm going to go with what works, especaially since having one less layer of layouts is a nice performance gain anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried after the remove transaction is committed, to call fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() before you do the add. I am wondering if these are getting out of order in the execution by the manager since they are not really executed at the time of the commit but placed onto the queue.

Comment: No such luck I'm afraid. I added your suggestion directly after the first call to commit. Nothing changed in either log output or the screen.

Comment: I checked the return values of `executePendingTransactons()` and it is reporting that it did in fact force the transaction to occur but it still does not display if I do both the remove and the add.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but in the remove line, do you mean to have String.value(i) rather than String.value(oldFragment)?

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo I made in posting the code through multiple updates. I have corrected it. Essentially the tag is just the index in the list.